# Click event not working on iPad with touch event

Tags: jquery, ipad, html, touch

I am using a click event on a page link. It works good on iPad's [Safari](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_%28web_browser%29), but when I use touch events on the same page then the click event stops working; only the touch event works there on the iPad.

Click event:

```
 link.onclick = onLinkClick;
```

Touch event:

```
$('#sdiv').bind({
    'touchstart': function (e) {
        onTouchStart(e, sdiv);
    }
});

$('#sdiv').bind({
    'touchend': function (e) {
        onTouchEnd(e);
    }
});

$('#sdiv').bind({
    'touchmove': function (e) {
        onTouchMove(e);
    }
});

$('#sdiv').bind({
    'touchcancel': function (e) {
        onTouchCancel(e);
    }
});
```

Comment: Is the `link` element is within `#sdiv` element? If so, then make sure you haven't used `event.preventDefault()` in your touch handlers.

Comment: yes `link` is within `$sdiv` and i also used `event.preventDefault()`.

Comment: no if i remove `event.preventDefault()` from touch handlers then click event works but it stops touch event.

Comment: Ya that is the point, you cannot have both at the same time if you use `event.preventDefault()` as per the documentation. Either you move `link` element out of that `#sdiv` or manually implement tapping on `link` element using `touchstart`, `touchend` events and a timer.

Comment: what exactly do you want to do for ipad and desktop? there is probably another approach you can use

Comment: ok now i got the answer i will use for ipad `var platform = navigator.platform; if( platform === 'iPad') {  _link.ontouchend = onLinkClick;} else { _link.onclick = onLinkClick; }`

Comment: @ketan: Has this issue been solved or answered?

Comment: You may want to explore a library like hammer.js to manage touch events for you http://eightmedia.github.com/hammer.js/

Comment: @TJ Yes I got answer and i wrote that on above comment.

Comment: @ketan Ok, cool. I suggest you answer your own question then.

Comment: Ok I answer My Quesion Below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I differentiate both platforms, **iPad** and **desktop**. Using '**navigator.platform**', if it's iPad then the **touch event** works, else the **Click event**.

```
 var platform = navigator.platform; 

 if( platform == 'iPad') { _link.ontouchend = onLinkClick;} 

  else { _link.onclick = onLinkClick; }
```

Thanks to all,