# jquery detecting the id of a sub menu item that has been touched

Tags: jquery

I have dropdown menus which work fine on a non-touch device but when viewed on an iPad for example the menu does not disappear on a choice being made/touched.

I can trigger an event on a menu item being touched:

```
    $(document).on('touchstart', function() {
         ....
    });
```

but I am not sure how to identify which ID has triggered the event.

I have tried:

```
        var selectedID = $(this).attr("id");
```

but this results in undefined. The menu structure is as follows:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="button_main" id="admin">Admin</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
        <button class="button_sub" id="admin_users">Users</button>
        <button class="button_sub" id="admin_depts">Departments</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I really need is the id of the main menu ID when a sub menu item is touched. Any pointers?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10975524/click-event-not-working-on-ipad-with-touch-event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$(document).on('touchstart', "button", function(event) {
     var selectedID = $(event.target).attr("id");
     console.log(selectedID);
});
```

So... On touchstart on a button... Not everywhere else. Then use the `event` to get that `target` property, which is the element that triggered it.

Comment: That's great - thank you. Slight improvement following your advice is '.dropdown-content' rather than 'button' so that limits to dropdown sub menu class only. Still need to identfy the main menu from the sub menu but that can be figureed out from the submenu id unless there is a better way.

Comment: Yes... If you think it's better. But if you have some padding on `dropdown-content`, you possibly will get an "undefined" id... You could use `.dropdown-content .button_sub` to be more specific here... If that is the concern ;)