# My jQuery (touchstart) not working on iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have used a jQuery function to collapse the content of the div tag. Unfortunately, this function doesn't seem to work on iPhone. Please help me to make it work, thanks!

My site: https://thuexedulich.danang.vn/thue-xe-da-nang/

```js
let touchEvent = 'ontouchstart' in window ? 'touchstart' : 'click';

$('.expand-button').on(touchEvent, function(){
  $('.cat-decs').toggleClass('-expanded');
  if ($('.cat-decs').hasClass('-expanded')) {
    $('.expand-button').html('Click to Hide');
  } else {
    $('.expand-button').html('Click to Read More');
  }
});
```

```css
.cat-decs {border-top: 3px solid var(--main-color)}
.expand-button {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    width: 30%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    color: var(--main-color)!important
}
/*.expand-button:hover {color: #fff!important}*/
.cat-decs{
  position: relative;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height .3s ease;
}
.cat-decs.-expanded {
  max-height: 100%;
}
.cat-decs:not(.-expanded)::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 1));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="entry-content cat-decs">
  <p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. </p>
  <p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. </p>
  <p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. </p>
  <p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. </p>
  <p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. </p>
</div>
<a class="expand-button btn btn-more">Click to Read More</a>
```

Comment: Why even use `touchstart` at all? The iPhone supports a good equivalent of the `click` event. Also, isn't the event `touchstart` and not `ontouchstart`? Just like its `click` and not `onclick`.

Comment: how do you want it to collapse?

Comment: you should use bind inside touch start fuction.. try and check this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10975524/click-event-not-working-on-ipad-with-touch-event

Comment: @somethinghere 
Can you give me an example of the code?

Comment: @Rojo I want to collapse my content in div.cat-decs. On PC, my function is good but on iPhone it not working :(

Comment: Just do `let touchEvent = 'click';` and it should just work on both easily.

Comment: @somethinghere I changed it to a click but it still doesn't work on the iPhone. My site: https://thuexedulich.danang.vn/thue-xe-da-nang/

Comment: Is the issue that your paragraph is overlapping your button? I have a hard time even clicking it on safari. Try adding `position: relative; z-index: 100;` to your button and see if you can now consistently click on mobile and desktop.

Comment: @somethinghere Yes, it works now on both mobile and desktop. Thank you for your help! ^^